# Geopy with GoogleV3 says Quota exceeded after only a few request

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geopy

Code:

```
    from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
for list in lista:
    'set place = the partial address data'
    place = list[0]
    geolocator = GoogleV3()
    'lookup location with geocoder'
    location = geolocator.geocode(place)
    'place the result in a sub-list with the original partial address'
    list[1] = (location.address)
```

I'm using Python 3 with Geopy to loop through a list of partial address data (street and city), look each item up with Geopy and return the full address (or at least Google's guess at the full address).

The code works, but after running through the first 4-5 items it throws the error:

> GeocoderQuotaExceeded: The given key has gone over the requests limit in the 24 
>   hour period or has submitted too many requests in too short a period of time.

I don't have a paid api key to use, but in previous research I found people using the GoogleV3 geocoder without an api key (with a 1k request per day limit).

Any ideas what is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Google will show detailed usage metrics for your key in the API console.

Comment: The policy has changed (there is likely nothing wrong with your code),  you need to enable billing with a credit card. Please see: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/ (As of June 11, 2018, you must enable billing with a credit card and have a valid API key for all of your projects)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a google support issue not a programming problem

Comment: @geocodezip - you are likely correct. I see they offer some free usage initially, after that does it charge for every request?

Comment: @geocodezip do you want to at least add your comment as an answer before closing? To my knowledge there isn't much info out there right now about this policy change so it may help people with similar issues understand what is happening. I kept finding old forum posts that didn't match what I was finding on google's support pages so it was kind of confusing (i.e. this may help others?)

Comment: Google updated the rules. Now you have to pay to get 1k request per day limit. Your code can only get one free geolocation per api key. I am trying to understand how to buy API key to make the geolocation. As soon as I understand it, I will tell here as answer - if you want.